# Ubuntu 16.04 (Lenovo Thinkpad Sl500) wireless driver not working

Tags: wifi, laptop

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad SL500 but the Wifi is not working, although the wired connection is still fine. 
Pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/16020359/
Here are the results of several commands:

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 005: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 006 Device 007: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

And `iwconfig`  :

```
enp12s0   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Also `lspci` :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
0c:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
0d:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 05)
0d:00.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 22)
0d:00.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 12)
0d:00.3 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller (rev 12)
```

I followed some advice from : http://www.linlap.com/lenovo_thinkpad_sl500 , but it seemed to be very cryptic and I didn't know how to load the drivers. Also tried to use nvdiswrapper but couldn't understand their instructions. 
Thank you very much

UPDATE: Tried this:

```
nmcli g
STATE         CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN    
disconnected  none          enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled
```

This was done when I unplugged the wired connection. 
And `sudo lshw -C network` :

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       logical name: enp12s0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:23:54:2a:b5:fd
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.31 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:28 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:fcfff000-fcffffff memory:fcfe0000-fcfeffff memory:feaf0000-feafffff
```

UPDATE 2: The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` was really strange, because there was nothing 
UPDATE 3:

```
lspci -k

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ICH9M LPC Interface Controller
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
0c:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
0d:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller
    Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
    Kernel modules: firewire_ohci
0d:00.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 22)
    Subsystem: Lenovo R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
0d:00.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 12)
    Subsystem: Lenovo R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: r592
    Kernel modules: r592
0d:00.3 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller (rev 12)
    Subsystem: Lenovo xD-Picture Card Controller
    Kernel driver in use: r852
    Kernel modules: r852
```

UPDATE 4: I just checked the SL500 Hardware Maintenance manual, and it saids: `Featue: PCI Express Mini Card` and

```
Description:
v ThinkPad 11b/g Wireless LAN Mini PCI Express Adapter
III
v Intel WiFi Link 5100
v Intel WiMAX/WiFi Link 5150
v Intel WiMAX/WiFi Link 5350
v Ericsson F3507g USA - Wireless WAN card
v Ericsson F3507g Other - Wireless WAN card
v Wireless USB PCI Express Half-Mini Card
```

UPDATE 5: Tried the suggestion with backport, but at the last command I got this result:

```
sudo make install
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 6 modules
  INSTALL /home/dangmanhtruong/backports-4.4.2-1/compat/compat.ko
At main.c:222:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  INSTALL /home/dangmanhtruong/backports-4.4.2-1/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/iwldvm.ko
At main.c:222:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  INSTALL /home/dangmanhtruong/backports-4.4.2-1/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
At main.c:222:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  INSTALL /home/dangmanhtruong/backports-4.4.2-1/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
At main.c:222:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  INSTALL /home/dangmanhtruong/backports-4.4.2-1/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
At main.c:222:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  INSTALL /home/dangmanhtruong/backports-4.4.2-1/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
At main.c:222:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  DEPMOD  4.4.0-21-generic
depmod will prefer updates/ over kernel/ -- OK!
Note:
You may or may not need to update your initramfs, you should if
any of the modules installed are part of your initramfs. To add
support for your distribution to do this automatically send a
patch against "update-initramfs.sh". If your distribution does not
require this send a patch with the '/usr/bin/lsb_release -i -s'
("Ubuntu") tag for your distribution to avoid this warning.

Your backported driver modules should be installed now.
Reboot.
```

What should I do? :(

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: @GAD3R there was nothing, even when I used sudo

Comment: `lspci -k` will give some informations about the network controller ?

Comment: try to download 'iwlwifi-5000-ucode-5.4.A.11.tar.gz' from https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi and copy the firmware to `/lib/firmware/`

Comment: What is the actual chipset of the wireless card? I'm not clear on that.

Comment: @GAD3R I have done as you requested :)

Comment: Is that work without problems?

Comment: @Faheem Mitha to be honest, I don't know for sure. I can't really find any way to see what the wireless card is, but some sites suggest that it's Intel 5100

Comment: @GAD3R actually I had downloaded the ucode file before I made this post, but it did not work and, I used the "cp" command as instructed but there was no output ,also the site said "You can then load the driver", but I don't know how to do that, am I supposed to recompile the kernel?

Comment: to load the driver type: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`

Comment: @DangManhTruong Yes, the provided information is quite coy. Have you checked the documentation provided with your laptop? Also, look at your system logs.

Comment: @GAD3R no result

Comment: @FaheemMitha I just updated what I found on the documentation. But I don't know how to see the system logs

Comment: I'm afraid that the Wireless LAN status is off, but even after turning the wifi switch nearby to on, it didn't work :(

Comment: @DangManhTruong Try `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/messages`, and `/var/log/kern.log`.

Comment: That description is confusing. Are those different choices for wifi card?

Comment: Using the hardware switch on the front/side, turn off the wireless. Power down and switch off completely. Switch on. Power back up again. Do you now get the device listed in `lsusb`?

Answer (score 1):

I had a big issue with the wireless speed connection on my Lenovo TP 410i and its Intel wirelesss 1000n board. In Ubuntu's wireless network configuration menu I always get 1Mbps connection and Internet speed test was always poor -obviously- I follow following instructions and it automatically changed to 54Mbps and Internet speed test result was much better.

```
T410i:~$ sudo rmmod iwldvm
T410i:~$ sudo rmmod iwlwifi
T410i:~$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

I don't know what all of that stuff does but it worked for me under Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest backport from [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.4.2/)

```
https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.4.2/backports-4.4.2-1.tar.gz
```

Install `linux-headers` and  `build-essential`

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
```

Then compile the module

```
tar xvf backports-4.4.2-1.tar.gz
cd backports-4.4.2-1
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot

Comment: There were some errors (written on my Update), but it said that "Your backported driver modules should be installed now.
Reboot." Should I ignore the errors?

Comment: please see my answer for that, sorry but my original post was becoming too long

Comment: When I typed "sudo rmmod iwlwifi" I got: "rmmod: ERROR: Module iwlwifi is not currently loaded". THen I typed: "sudo modprobe iwldvm iwlwifi" , nothing happened. I then typed: "sudo rmmod iwlwifi", but now: "rmmod: ERROR: Module iwlwifi is in use by: iwldvm
". What should i do? :(

Comment: `iwldvm` depend on `iwlwifi` maybe it's the right module , first try `sudo rmmod iwldvm `  , `sudo rmmod iwlwifi` and `modprobe iwldvm iwlwifi` again try to reboot and bring up your wifi card `sudp ip link set wlan0 up`

Comment: Tried "sudo rmmod iwldvm " but "rmmod: ERROR: Module iwldvm is not currently loaded" :(